# asking for user String input without spaces in java

Tags: java, string

I need the program to return a message if the user input a string with blank spaces.
for example "this is my house" is not allowed, "thisismyhouse" is allowed.
right now I use this code to check for blank spaces

```
    for(int i = 0; i < blabla.length(); i++) {
        if (blabla.charAt(i) == ' ')
            flag++;
        }
    }
    if (flag != 0) {
        System.out.println("input must not contain spaces");
    }
```

I wonder if there's a built in function like 'blabla.equals' etc for this purpose? 
or a better way to write this?

Comment: how about using String.contains ?

Comment: `blablabla.contains(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
if(input.contains(" "))
   System.out.println("input must not contain spaces");
```

Solution 2:

```
if(input.indexOf(" ")>=0)
   System.out.println("input must not contain spaces");
```

Solution 3:

You can simply allow the user to enter spaces and remove them yourselves instead:

```
 input = input.replaceAll(" ","");
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   if (blabla != null && blabla.contains (" ")) {
      System.out.println("input must not contain spaces");
      return;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick.

```
if(blabla.contains(" ")){};
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 0):

A little search would give you the answer but...
There is a method defined in [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) returns a boolean value for that purpose already.

```
if (blabla.contains(" ")) {
System.out.println("input must not contain spaces");
}
```

You can review the methods of String...